# Filter JSON object by the values true, NULL or 'null'

Tags: json, postgresql, filter

I want to add a new column named "MyJsonObject" to the table "Test". The new column should only contain values if they are true, not NULL or 'null' as text.

NULLs as a value can be filtered with `json_strip_nulls`, but how can I filter the other values, false and 'null' as text?

`json_strip_null` works only for NULL Values

```
myjsonstring                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
{"column_1":false,"column_2":false,"column_3":true,"column_4":"red"}   | 
{"column_1":false,"column_2":false,"column_3":true,"column_4":"yellow"}| 
{"column_1":false,"column_2":true,"column_3":true}                     | 
{"column_1":true,"column_2":false,"column_3":true,"column_4":"NULL"}   |
```

I want to get:

```
myjsonstring                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
{"column_3":true,"column_4":"red"}   |
{"column_3":true,"column_4":"yellow"}|
{"column_2":true,"column_3":true}    |
{"column_1":true,"column_3":true     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest the elements and then aggregate them back:

```
select t.myjsonstring, x.new_json
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_object_agg(k,v) as new_json
    from jsonb_each(t.myjsonstring) as j(k,v)
    where v is not null
      and v::text not in ('false', 'NULL')
  ) as x
```